# Modeling Relay Cursor Connections

Tags: graphql, relay

I'm building a graphql application  where a `User` can have a bunch of `Entries`. It is an n to m relationship, with the intermediary table/edge holding additional information about the relationship.
My graphql schema looks something like this :

```
type User {
    id: ID!,
    entries(…): [UserEntry]
}

type UserEntry {
    id: ID!,
    user: User,
    entry: Entry,
    someOtherAttribute: String,
    yetAnotherAttribute: String
}

type Entry {...}

type Query {
  me: User!
  userEntry(userEntryId: ID!): UserEntry!
}
```

I want to add cursor style pagination to that `entries` field, following the [Relay Cursor Connections Specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm).
So I guess `UserEntry` would become something like this :

```
type UserEntryEdge {
    node: Entry,
    cursor: String,
    someOtherAttribute: String,
    yetAnotherEdgeAttribute: String
}
```

But I want to still be able to query the `UserEntry`/`UserEntryEdge` directly, and in that context the `cursor` field for example would be irrelevant.

**What's the best way to design my graphql schema to be able to query edges data directly ?**

*(FYI: I'm using nodejs and the apollo framework suite both on server and client)*

Comment: So you want to query `Entry` directly? And what you mean under **directly**? Could you provide example queries you want to work?

Comment: I could Query `Entry` just fine here. I want to be able to still query UserEntry ! I've added the definition of my current queries.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually modelling your schema like this

```
[User] hasAndBelongsToMany [Entry]
```

But you could think about it like

```
[User] hasMany [UserEntry] hasOne [Entry]
    and
[Entry] hasMany [UserEntry] hasOne [User]
```

So, going back to your GraphQL Schema:

```
type User {
    id: ID!,
    userEntriesConnection(…): UserEntriesConnection!
}

type UserEntriesConnection {
    edges: [UserEntryEdge]!,
    pageInfo: ...
}

type UserEntryEdge {
    cursor: String!,
    node: UserEntry,
}

type UserEntry {
    id: ID!,
    user: User,
    entry: Entry,
    someOtherAttribute: String,
    yetAnotherAttribute: String
}

type Entry { ... }

type Query {
  me: User!
  userEntry(userEntryId: ID!): UserEntry!
}
```

Would that fit your need ? The queries would be more verbose, because there is more depth, but it is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to query `UserEntry` directly then I guess you should keep it as a separate type in your schema and not transform it into `Edge` type.

So just keep both `UserEntry` and `UserEntryEdge`.

The resulting schema may look like:

```
type User {
    id: ID!,
    entries(…): [UserEntryConnection]
}

type UserEntryConnection {
  edges: [UserEntryEdge]
  nodes: [Entry] # shortcut (GitHub does like that)
  pageInfo: PageInfo!
}

type UserEntryEdge {
    node: Entry,
    cursor: String,
    info: UserEntry # To not duplicate attributes, you can use UserEntry type here
}

type UserEntry {
    id: ID!,
    user: User,
    entry: Foo,
    someOtherAttribute: String,
    yetAnotherAttribute: String
}

type Entry {...}

type Query {
  me: User!
  userEntry(userEntryId: ID!): UserEntry! # keep userEntry field as is
}
```

Comment: I've thought about doing it that way, but it feels a bit awkward to me that `Entry` is reachable both from the field `node` of `UserEntryEdge` and the field `entry` of `UserEntry`.
Maybe I should just expose a merged version of `Entry` and `UserEntry` in the api...
Thanks for your help